# Pandas: read_html

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to extract US states from wiki URL, and for which I'm using Python Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
f_states = pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
```

However, the above code is giving me an error L

> ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
>    in ()
>         1 import pandas as pd
>   ----> 2 f_states = pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
>
> if flavor in ('bs4', 'html5lib'):
>       662         if not _HAS_HTML5LIB:
>   --> 663             raise ImportError("html5lib not found, please install it")
>       664         if not _HAS_BS4:
>       665             raise ImportError("BeautifulSoup4 (bs4) not found, please install it")
>   ImportError: html5lib not found, please install it

I installed html5lib and beautifulsoup4 as well, but it is not working. 
Can someone help pls.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Running Python 3.4 on a mac

New pyvenv

```
pip install pandas
pip install lxml
pip install html5lib
pip install BeautifulSoup4
```

Then run your example and it should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
f_states=   pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
```

Comment: thanks, this worked. Although I have installed all of them, but I reinstalled it, and opened a new instance, and it worked. thanks

Comment: Same thing here @TimSeed, I installed everything using pip, then had to relaunch a new instance.

Comment: You don't need `html5lib` as it's only a fall back if lxml isn't present. Read about `flavors` in the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_html.html)

Comment: Same thing here. Need to relaunch (for a few times) to get it work.

Answer (score 4):

Also consider conda installing your required packages at https://www.continuum.io/downloads. Instead of pip installing, you would conda install your packages.

```
$ conda install html5lib
```

Answer (score 2):

if your environment is Anaconda Jupiter notebook.

you need another set of install comment:

```
conda install lxml
conda install html5lib
conda install BeautifulSoup4
```

then run the python code in Jupiter notebook.

```
import pandas as pd
f_states=   pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to install lxml using pip.

```
pip install lxml
```

this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For that you just need to install

```
pip install pandas
pip install lxml
```

and then you have to import those and run your program

```
import pandas as pd
f_states=pd.read_html('https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._states')
```