# pd.read_html bs4 not found after it was imported successfully

Tags: python, pandas, beautifulsoup

I think the image is self explanatory but basically I have successfully installed and updated bs4, imported it successfully as you see in the above Jupyter Notebook entry but nevertheless it tells me it didn't find it when it tried to run pd.read_html()

[Screen Shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bKVjh.png)

Comment: What's your bs4 version?

Comment: BeautifulSoup4 in ./Library/Python/3.6/lib/python/site-packages (4.6.3)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34555135/pandas-read-html/34555201

Comment: I already had the seen that post but it didn't work before I actually import html5lib. Thanks for the help!